# Linked list class in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is supposed to create a single linked list class with head and tail pointers, along with insertion, delete, and search functions.

I tested it on my machine and it seems to run without errors or warnings.

```
#include <iostream>

using  std::cout;
using  std::cin;
using  std::endl;

struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *next;
};

class linked_list {
    private:
        struct node *head;
        struct node *tail;
    public:
        linked_list() {
            head = nullptr;
            tail = nullptr;
        }

        void create(int key) {
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            head = temp;
            tail = head;
        }


        void insert(int key) {
            if (key < head->key) {
                insert_beginning(key);
            }
            else if ((head->next == nullptr) || (key > tail->key)) {
                insert_end(key);
            }
            else {
                insert_middle(key);
            }
        }

        void insert_beginning(int key) {
            if (head->next == nullptr) {
                tail = head;
            }
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }

        void insert_end(int key) {
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            if (head->next == nullptr) {
                head->next = temp;
                tail = temp;
            }
            else {
                tail->next = temp;
            }
            tail = temp;
        }


        void insert_middle(int key) {
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;

            struct node *current = head;
            struct node *prev = current;

            while (current->key < temp->key) {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            prev->next = temp;
            temp->next = current;
        } 

        void delete_node(int key) {
            if (head == nullptr) {
                cout << "List is empty\n";
                return;
            }

            if (head->key == key) {
                if (head->next == nullptr) {
                    delete(head);
                    head = tail = nullptr;
                }
                struct node *temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                delete(temp);
            }
            else {
                struct node *current = head;
                struct node *prev = current;

                while ((current->key != key) && (current->next != nullptr)) {
                    prev = current;
                    current = current->next;
                }

                if ((current->key != key) && (current->next == nullptr)) {
                    cout << "Key not found\n";
                }
                else if ((current->key == key) && (current->next == nullptr)) {
                    tail = prev;
                    prev->next = nullptr;
                    delete(current);
                }
                else {
                    prev->next = current->next;
                    delete(current);
                }

            }
        }

        void search_node(int key) {
            if (head->key == key || tail->key == key) {
                cout << "Node found\n";
                return;
            }
            struct node *current = head;
            while ((current->key != key) && (current->next != nullptr)) {
                current = current->next;
            }

            if (current->key == key) {
                cout << "Node found\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Node not found\n";
            }
        }

        void print_nodes(void) {
            struct node *current = head;
            while (current != nullptr) {
                cout << current->key << '\n';
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
};


int main(void) {
    linked_list list;

    list.create(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
        list.insert(i);
    }

    list.search_node(5);
    list.search_node(0);
    list.search_node(-1);

    list.delete_node(19);
    list.delete_node(0);

    list.print_nodes();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty good start! The writing is very clear, and it's pretty easy to understand what's going on. I see a few things you could do differently.

## Ease of Use

I notice that to use this class, a caller would need to instantiate a `linked_list`, call `create()` exactly once, and then call `insert()` repeatedly to insert the nodes. I think you're giving callers a lot of credit to think they'll remember all those steps each time. As it stands right now, if a caller accidentally calls `create()` twice, you'll leak memory! The node from the first call will be unhooked from the list, but not freed.

There are a few ways you could make this easier. You could either make a second constructor that takes a key and creates a new list with a single node in it. But an empty list can be useful, so I wouldn't make it the only constructor.

A better way would be to simply move the code from `create()` into `insert()` and add a condition around it. Something like this:

```
void insert(int key) {
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = new struct node;
        temp->key = key;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        head = temp;
        tail = head;
    }
    else if (key < head->key)
    {
        // ... etc.
```

This way a caller can simply instantiate a `linked_list` and start inserting nodes.

## Give Your Class Some Privacy

You've done the right thing by making `head` and `tail` private. That prevents a user of this class from messing them up. It seems like `insert_beginning()`, `insert_middle()`, and `insert_end()` should also be private since calling them from the outside could put an object in a bad state. For example, a user of the class could call `insert_beginning()` with a `key` that's greater than the key currently in `head`. But even better than that would be to simplify the logic for insertion as described in the next section.

## Simplify

It's interesting that you have 3 different insertion methods. There's a special case for inserting at the head and inserting at the tail of the list. That could be an optimization in some cases, or it could be a performance hit doing a bunch of extra checking that isn't normally needed. Without profiling, it's hard to say for sure. But it does complicate the code. Personally, I think making the code more straightforward will have a bigger payoff, so I would suggest making a single `insert()` method that handles all the cases.

The insertion can be broken down into 2 steps: 1) find where to insert the node, 2) actually insert it and make all the links before and after work properly. I would do it something like this:

```
void insert(int key) {
    // Find the predecessor node
    struct node* prev = nullptr;
    struct node* curr = head;
    
    while ((curr != nullptr) && (key > curr->key))
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    
    // Create the new node
    struct node* newNode = new struct node;
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    
    // Insertion
    if (curr == nullptr)
    {
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = curr;
    }
    
    if (prev == nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

You can use similar logic for `search_node()` and `delete_node()`.

## Errors

You have no destructor for this class, so it never gets cleaned up, leaking memory every time it's used. You really should add one.

## Tests

It's great that you've written some code to test out your class. You should make a few more tests that test harder edge cases. For example, when writing the `insert()` method above, I ran it with your tests and it worked. Then I changed the test to generate 20 random numbers, and it started dropping a few. That's because my logic was bad in one spot, and if the key was less than the first node, the key would not get properly inserted. So a test for things out-of-order is important here!

Comment: Thanks. If I want to move the 3 insertions to private, I only have to copy paste them there, right? No other changes need to be done I believe.

I had originally used `rand()` for testing but couldn't keep it since I can't use search or delete on numbers I don't know.

Comment: Yes, you only need to move those functions into the `private` section. (You can add as many `private`, `public`, or `protected` sections as you like. I've seen people do it for every single method. But I prefer just having 1 of each.) As for testing, it makes sense to do both - a sequential set where you can search for a specific node, and maybe another one with random values. (If you do go with random numbers, I recommend using a fixed random seed so the sequence is reproducible. Having tests that do something different on every run can lead to bugs.)